# Why white borders in JavaFX Polyline?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

```
xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polyline?>

<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Polyline points="0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0" strokeLineCap="BUTT" strokeType="CENTERED" strokeWidth="15.0">
      </Polyline>
   </children>
</Group>
```

Someone knows why, when opening the above `.fxml` in Scene Builder, I see white borders on the down side and on the right side of the `Polyline`?

[image: The polyline with white borders]

Note: there are no css nor hard-coded dimensions associated with the above fxml. I open just the plain fxml as shown.

Comment: Having only a Polyline in the fxml is kind of strange.  Normally SceneBuilder used for performing layouts in containers like panes and groups, but you don’t have any of those.

Comment: I leaved only the polyline in my post just to have a minimal example. Putting the polyline inside a Group tag (for instance) the final result does not change, I still continue to see the white borders.

`<Group xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Polyline points="0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0" strokeLineCap="BUTT" strokeType="CENTERED" strokeWidth="15.0">
      </Polyline>
   </children>
</Group>`

Comment: ok @trashgod I have just edited my original example adding the Group tag to the fxml.

Comment: Is the `Group` larger than the `Polyline`? If so, then you're likely just seeing what's behind the `Polyline`, and that happens to be a white-ish background.

Comment: I don’t know @Slaw I have no css nor hard-coded dimensions associated with the above fxml. Don’t should be the Group larger “exactly” like the inner children polyline?

Comment: What happens when you load the `.fxml` and add it to a scene?

Comment: @trashgod I have just tried, it happens just the same. Loading the fxml in a Scene from Java, I don't see "visually" the white borders (I suppose because they are "transparent"), but opening the Scene with Scenic View, the Bounds are +1 pixel bigger! I was expecting the Bounds as 100x15 but actually they are 101x16! So the white borders in Scene Builder are in consequence of that pixel around the Polyline added by "something", native CSS?

Comment: As the default stroke is null, you might experiment with various `stroke*` properties. I suspect an anomaly in Scene Builder. Are you by any chance running it on Windows?

Comment: @trashgod Yes, the same both on Mac and Windows. I have tried to change some stroke properties, and also tried to open an issue on Scene Builder community. Anyway, no news so far.